# ESlint formatting - line up declarations?

Tags: eslint

Is there a rule or plug-in that will cause an es-lint error or warning if declarations within a scope are not spaced like the below, with the same  alignment of assignment operator?

```
var a   = 'a';
var bb  = 'b';
var ccc = 'd';
var x   = function () {
    this.thing = 1;
    this.o     = 2;
    return this;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you're looking for the [`indent` rule](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent). By default `indent` uses an indent of `4` spaces which it looks like you want.

So you should be able to enable `indent` and you'll be good to go.

Comment: I'm looking to align the assignment operators, or at least maintain the alignment I created manually.

Comment: Apologies, the question was a little vague and didn't specify the alignment of the assignment operators.